# Django платежи Liqpay @method_decorator

Tags: python, django, методы, платежи, liqpay

Добрый день подскажите что не так, делал все по инструкции

views.py

```
class PayView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pay.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        else:
            session_key=request.session.session_key
            name=str(session_key)
            user= User.objects.filter(username=name).first()
            customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=user).first()
        orders = Order.objects.filter(customer=customer).order_by('-id')[:1].first()

        liqpay = LiqPay(settings.LIQPAY_PUBLIC_KEY, settings.LIQPAY_PRIVATE_KEY)
        params = {
            'action': 'pay',
            'amount': '1',
            'currency': 'UAH',
            'description': 'Payment for clothes',
            'version': '3',
            'sandbox': 0, # sandbox mode, set to 1 to enable it
            'server_url': 'http://127.0.0.1/pay-callback/', # url to callback view
            'result_url':'http://127.0.0.1/pay-callback/'
        }
        signature = liqpay.cnb_signature(params)
        data = liqpay.cnb_data(params)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'signature': signature, 'data': data})


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class PayCallbackView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        liqpay = LiqPay(settings.LIQPAY_PUBLIC_KEY, settings.LIQPAY_PRIVATE_KEY)
        data = request.POST.get('data')
        print('data',data)
        signature = request.POST.get('signature')
        sign = liqpay.str_to_sign(settings.LIQPAY_PRIVATE_KEY + data + settings.LIQPAY_PRIVATE_KEY)
        if sign == signature:
            print('callback is valid')
        response = liqpay.decode_data_from_str(data)
        print('callback data', response)
        return HttpResponse('/')
```

pay.html

```
<div id="liqpay_checkout"></div>
<script>
  window.LiqPayCheckoutCallback = function() {
    LiqPayCheckout.init({
      data: "{{data}}",
      signature: "{{signature}}",
      embedTo: "#liqpay_checkout",
      mode: "embed" // embed || popup,
        }).on("liqpay.callback", function(data){
      console.log(data.status);
      console.log(data);
      }).on("liqpay.ready", function(data){
        // ready
      }).on("liqpay.close", function(data){
        // close
    });
  };
</script>
<script src="//static.liqpay.ua/libjs/checkout.js" async></script>
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^pay/$', PayView.as_view(), name='pay_view'),
    url(r'^pay-callback/$', PayCallbackView.as_view(), name='pay_callback'),
```

Виджет показывает , оплату принимает но до класса class PayCallbackView(View): не доходит, не могу проверить статус платежа , подскажите в чем дело

Comment: есть мнение что `Liqpay` никак не пришлёт вам колбэк на `127.0.0.1`

Comment: здесь уже дошло  xD , пробую на хероку , получаю ошибку когда приходит ответ internal Server Error: /pay-callback/

TypeError at /pay-callback/
must be str, not dict

Comment: а на какую строчку то ругается хоть? ну и как бы ошибка говорит сама за себя

Comment: Проблема решилась сама собой или методом тыка xD был бы благодарен если бы подсказали как сделать редирект на главную после успешной оплаты, не пойму куда вписать success url